# Proper way to add dynamic HTML through .ajax() request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have this example of the success part of a JSON Facebook Graph API request,

```
success: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                    $(res.data).each(function(index, value){

                        var pic = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + value.id + '/picture?width=200&height=200';

                        $('<img class="hover" src="'+pic+'" width="200" height="200">').load(function(){
                            $(this).appendTo("#results").fadeIn("fast");
                            $(this).wrap('<a href="http://facebook.com/'+value.id+'" target="_blank"></a>');
                        })

                    });
                },
```

That looks for the recieved data objects, puts the page-id picture inside an img tag, and when it's already loaded, it appends it to the `#results` div.

However I don't have control in `img .hover` elements. I tried with

```
$("img.hover").hover(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut() //for example
            });
```

and nothing happens. I suspect that's because any img did exist when the document was created. So, how could get those new elements?

Comment: "I suspect that's because any img did exist when the document was created." We have a winner! :)

Comment: Yes :D, so, what would be a good practice for those cases?

Comment: Using JQuery's `on` method, which is built explicitly for this purpose, as @ArunPJohny suggested.

Comment: Yes, because I had put everything inside $(function(){ ... }), thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover) method is a shortcut for registering [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) events so

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'img.hover', function () {
    $(this).fadeIn() //for example
}).on('mouseleave', 'img.hover', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut() //for example
});
```

Comment: yes, however any img div exist before at the creation of the document. How is it handle dynamically?

Comment: that is how event delegation works... these events from each event gets propagated to the document object

Comment: oh, I see you've changed to $(document).on , I'll try that way